# Calculation of Easter Sunday with earliest and latest date

Tags: java, eclipse

"I have been assigned the task of programming a calculator in Java (C# would also work) that, based on the current year and user input, outputs the dates for the earliest and latest Easter Sunday. The program should work in such a way that the user enters a number representing the number of years to be checked in the future. The current year is 2023. The output should then display the earliest and latest dates on which Easter Sunday occurred within the specified number of years.

Unfortunately, my code doesn't seem to solve it. The calculation of Easter Sundays is correct, but for some reason, filtering for the earliest and latest Easter Sunday doesn't seem to work."

```
        import java.time.LocalDate;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Ostersonntag3 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Bitte geben Sie eine Anzahl an Jahren ein: ");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();

        LocalDate spätesterOstersonntag = LocalDate.MAX;
        LocalDate frühesterOstersonntag = LocalDate.MIN;

        int currentYear = 2023;

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            LocalDate ostersonntag = berechneOstersonntag(currentYear + 
        i);

            if (ostersonntag.isBefore(spätesterOstersonntag)) {
                spätesterOstersonntag = ostersonntag;
            }

            if (ostersonntag.isAfter(frühesterOstersonntag)) {
                frühesterOstersonntag = ostersonntag;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Spaetester Ostersonntag: " + 
        spätesterOstersonntag);
        System.out.println("Fruehester Ostersonntag: " + 
        frühesterOstersonntag);

        scanner.close();
        }
 
        private static LocalDate berechneOstersonntag(int jahr) {
        int a = jahr % 19;
        int b = jahr % 4;
        int c = jahr % 7;
        int m = (8 * (jahr / 100) + 13) / 25 - 2;
        int s = jahr / 100 - jahr / 400 - 2;
        int n = (6 + s) % 7;
        int d = (m + 19 * a) % 30;

        if (d == 29) {
            d = 28;
        }

        if (d == 28 && a >= 11) {
            d = 27;
        }

        int e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + n) % 7;

        int tag = 21 + d + e + 1;
        int monat;

        if (tag > 31) {
            tag = tag % 31;
            monat = 4;
        } else {
            monat = 3;
        }

        return LocalDate.of(jahr, monat, tag);
        }
        }
```

The Input is as you can see a number (int) and the Output that i want is a date (for example 2023.04.22, etc.) the dates should represent the earliest and latest easter sunday in the amount of years the user put in.
But the Output does not seem to be giving me the correct dates:
[(for example the input is 20; the output is 2023.04.16 as the latest easter sunday and 2023.04.20 is the date for the closest easter sunday)
(But if the Input is 200; the output is 2023.04.16 for the latest and 2023.04.14 for the earliest easter sunday)
(And if the input is 30; the output is 2023.04.16 for the latest and 2023.03.31 for the earliest easter sunday)].
This does not make sense for me like at all??

Comment: Please note that SO is an english-only site. Also there are too many infos missing. You said that your code doesn't do what it should. *What* should it do? Where is your code? What is expected and what is actually happening?

Comment: Sorry first time here

Comment: *"... for some reason, filtering for the earliest and latest Easter Sunday doesn't seem to work."* - Tell us explicitly what output you are expecting and what output you are getting.   And the inputs ...

Comment: Which Easter?  In the Western world, Easter in 2023 was April 9th.  In the Orthodox world, April 16th.

Comment: The easter sunday of the Western world. I`m in europe.

Comment: I know that Easter can occur between March 22 and April 25 inclusive.  But its date is determined by the first full moon of Spring.  Your code may well be computing that but using single letters for values does not really explain what you're doing.  I presume you will fully document your code but you should also use meaningful variable names.

Comment: @WJS I think at least some of the variables are taken from [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_Easter#Gauss's_Easter_algorithm) or the ones that follow it.

Comment: @VGR Yep.  Interesting article which I may study at some point. But the OP's problem was using `isBefore` and `isAfter` to check for differences which also include the year.  The OP only wants day of year differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are incrementing years. And using the `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods also include the year which is incorrectly reporting `min` and `max` dates for Easter. Example. `2023-04-09 isBefore 2024-03-31` from a date perspective but not from a `month/day` perspective. Note: I had to print the actual values you were comparing to see what was going on and at first it wasn't obvious to me.  *Print statements are your friend when it comes to debugging*.  So you just compare the day of the year to previous days of the year for Easter. So here is what I did.

- define a comparator to compare month and day using the day of year.
- initialize your `min` and `max` to the current year date for Easter.
- then starting with '1', increment your years.

```
int x = 20;

int currentYear = 2023;
Comparator<LocalDate> comp = Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::getDayOfYear);

LocalDate ostersonntag = berechneOstersonntag(currentYear);
LocalDate spätesterOstersonntag = ostersonntag;
LocalDate frühesterOstersonntag = ostersonntag;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
       ostersonntag = berechneOstersonntag(currentYear + 
    i);

        if (comp.compare(ostersonntag, spätesterOstersonntag) > 0) {
            spätesterOstersonntag = ostersonntag;
        } else if (comp.compare(ostersonntag, frühesterOstersonntag) < 0) {
            frühesterOstersonntag = ostersonntag;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Spaetester Ostersonntag: " + 
    spätesterOstersonntag);
    System.out.println("Fruehester Ostersonntag: " + 
    frühesterOstersonntag);     
}
```

prints

```
Spaetester Ostersonntag: 2038-04-25
Fruehester Ostersonntag: 2035-03-25
```

Note:  Another issue is that you and I are using different calculations to determine Easter. I used [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_Easter#Gauss%27s_Easter_algorithm) posted by @VGR.  I verified the above using [Easter Dates](https://www.census.gov/data/software/x13as/genhol/easter-dates.html#par_textimage_1067001717)

Comment: Thanks for the help. By using the comparator the code finaly works. I struggled for at least 1,5 Weeks to find a solution for my problem.